# Centering a figure with multiple graphics to the page width rather than the text column width

Tags: horizontal-alignment

So I am still new to LaTeX. I have a figure that has 2 graphics side by side each with their own respective captions. My problem is that by default, LaTeX wants to allign the leftmost side of the left graphic with the lefthand side of my column of text. This is what I have as of now...

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure1.png}
\caption{Figure 1 caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{figure2.png}
\caption{Figure 2 caption}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The double graphics aspect of this code works very well. I just need the whole figure to be centered with the page so that it doesn't look lopsided to the right like it currently is.

Comment: If you know it is on an odd or even page (or you are using `[oneside]`) then simply `\hspace*{-3cm}\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}..` where 3cm is replaced by whatever offset you need

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just for demo
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{adjustbox}{center,width=\textwidth}     %%<-------- this added
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure 1 caption}
\label{fig:fig1}
\end{minipage}
\quad
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure 2 caption}
\label{fig:fig2}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustbox}  %% <------------- and this
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]